# powermt display, (device not found) in RHEL6.7

Tags: linux, emc

I installed EMCpower.LINUX-6.0.0.00.00-158.el6.x86_64 on RHEL7, register it. but when initiate "#powermt display", it returns Device(s) not found.

Also installed QLogic-SuperInstaller-REL2015U1-20150630-6, and HBA is loaded on kernel.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've *disabled* the built-in multipathing software (multipathd)?

You should install the ***sg3_utils*** package if you have not done so already ( `yum -y install sg3_utils` )... this will allow you to issue the command `rescan-scsi-bus.sh`, which scans the bus and issues a LIP. You should then be able to see the paths in `powermt display`.

If not, download and install '***inq***' from EMC support and see if you can see the luns in there.

Good article on ***online*** storage reconfiguration in RHEL here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/index.html

Info on the sg3_utils usage here:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/rescan-scsi-bus.html